# Finding the generators of $SU(3)$ different from the Gell-Mann matrices?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I want to find a set of generators of SU(3) different from the Gell-Mann matrices. How should I go about it? Can I construct it in such a way that at least three of the 8 generators when squared gives identity?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: The Gell-Mann matrices are basis for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, not generators for the group $SU(3)$. So what you need to do is to consider all possible bases for traceless Hermitian matrices of size $3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So, can we come with a representation so that the matrices squared gives  identity like in the case of Pauli matrices?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Why do you need such a representation ? What is really your aim ?

Comment: Such a representation in which for example consider A1, A2,A3 (three matrices in the new basis)..if squared gives me identity then, it will be possible to derive an identity(like the cos-sin identity for pauli matrices) for the exponentiation of the Hamiltonian involving A1 A2 and A3.